# Error when splitting a string into an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

Basically, I can't trim it unless it's in a message box.. it's hard to explain.
Here's 2 Images:
1. http://gyazo.com/83b0a996e607f7013d998f6f800650f1
2. http://gyazo.com/e1fe9d8adb4a522479f6621d29e90e9d

```
Dim value As String = ary(0).Trim()
        'Dim value1 As String = ary(1).Trim()

        Dim R As String
        Dim G As String
        Dim B As String

        Dim outline As String
        Dim outlineColor As String


        R = Chr(34) & "MouseColorR" & Chr(34)
        G = Chr(34) & "MouseColorG" & Chr(34)
        B = Chr(34) & "MouseColorB" & Chr(34)

        outline = Chr(34) & "ThickMouseEdges" & Chr(34)
        outlineColor = Chr(34) & "ThickMouseEdgesPackedColor" & Chr(34)
        'based on the value after the equals sign, do something



        If value = R Then
            MsgBox(ary(1).Trim(Chr(44)))

        ElseIf value = G Then
            MsgBox("finally")

        ElseIf value = B Then
            MsgBox("finally")

        ElseIf value = outline Then
            MsgBox("finally")
```

this works^^^^

this doesnt:

```
        Dim value As String = ary(0).Trim()
       this is the error---> Dim value1 As String = ary(1).Trim()

        Dim R As String
        Dim G As String
        Dim B As String

        Dim outline As String
        Dim outlineColor As String


        R = Chr(34) & "MouseColorR" & Chr(34)
        G = Chr(34) & "MouseColorG" & Chr(34)
        B = Chr(34) & "MouseColorB" & Chr(34)

        outline = Chr(34) & "ThickMouseEdges" & Chr(34)
        outlineColor = Chr(34) & "ThickMouseEdgesPackedColor" & Chr(34)
        'based on the value after the equals sign, do something



        If value = R Then
            MsgBox(ary(1).Trim(Chr(44)))

        ElseIf value = G Then
            MsgBox("finally")

        ElseIf value = B Then
            MsgBox("finally")

        ElseIf value = outline Then
            MsgBox("finally")

        ElseIf value = outlineColor Then
            MsgBox("finally")
```

and the error is :An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Terraria Smart Cursor.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Whole Code:

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub NsCheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object) Handles NsCheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    NsGroupBox2.Enabled = NsCheckBox1.Checked

End Sub

Private Sub NsTrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object) Handles NsTrackBar1.Scroll
    NsLabel4.Value1 = NsTrackBar1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub NsTrackBar2_Scroll(sender As Object) Handles NsTrackBar2.Scroll
    NsLabel5.Value1 = NsTrackBar2.Value
End Sub

Private Sub NsTrackBar3_Scroll(sender As Object) Handles NsTrackBar3.Scroll
    NsLabel6.Value1 = NsTrackBar3.Value
End Sub

Private Sub NsTrackBar6_Scroll(sender As Object) Handles NsTrackBar6.Scroll
    NsLabel9.Value1 = NsTrackBar6.Value
End Sub

Private Sub NsTrackBar5_Scroll(sender As Object) Handles NsTrackBar5.Scroll
    NsLabel8.Value1 = NsTrackBar5.Value
End Sub

Private Sub NsTrackBar4_Scroll(sender As Object) Handles NsTrackBar4.Scroll
    NsLabel7.Value1 = NsTrackBar4.Value
End Sub

Private Sub NsButton1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NsButton1.Click
    If ColorDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        NsLabel4.Value1 = ColorDialog1.Color.R
        NsLabel5.Value1 = ColorDialog1.Color.G
        NsLabel6.Value1 = ColorDialog1.Color.B

        NsTrackBar1.Value = NsLabel4.Value1
        NsTrackBar2.Value = NsLabel5.Value1
        NsTrackBar3.Value = NsLabel6.Value1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NsButton2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NsButton2.Click
    If ColorDialog2.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        NsLabel9.Value1 = ColorDialog2.Color.R
        NsLabel8.Value1 = ColorDialog2.Color.G
        NsLabel7.Value1 = ColorDialog2.Color.B

        NsTrackBar6.Value = NsLabel9.Value1
        NsTrackBar5.Value = NsLabel8.Value1
        NsTrackBar4.Value = NsLabel7.Value1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'reads each line from the text file one at a time
    For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadLines("C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\My Games\Terraria\config.json")


        'split the string by equals sign
        Dim ary As String() = line.Split(":")


        Dim value As String = ary(0).Trim()
        Dim value1 As String = ary(1).Trim()

        Dim R As String
        Dim G As String
        Dim B As String

        Dim outline As String
        Dim outlineColor As String


        R = Chr(34) & "MouseColorR" & Chr(34)
        G = Chr(34) & "MouseColorG" & Chr(34)
        B = Chr(34) & "MouseColorB" & Chr(34)

        outline = Chr(34) & "ThickMouseEdges" & Chr(34)
        outlineColor = Chr(34) & "ThickMouseEdgesPackedColor" & Chr(34)
        'based on the value after the equals sign, do something



        If value = R Then
            MsgBox(ary(1).Trim(Chr(44)))

        ElseIf value = G Then
            MsgBox("finally")

        ElseIf value = B Then
            MsgBox("finally")

        ElseIf value = outline Then
            MsgBox("finally")

        ElseIf value = outlineColor Then
            MsgBox("finally")

        End If



    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Please post a short but complete example as *code*. There's no reason to use images here.

Comment: It's very easy to explain: you paste the code into your question and say you are getting a ArgumentOutOfRangeException and say which line it is occurring on.

Comment: This still isn't a short but complete example. It's neither short *nor* complete, nor does it tell us which value you're splitting. It's also unclear why you've tagged this with C# when there's no C#. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: your `ary` variable only contains element 0, not element 1. The piece  of code you have pasted is therefore not the cause of your problem; it occurs earlier, assuming you even need `value1` (whatever that might be; please use meaningful variable names in your code) as you do not then use it in what you've posted so far.

Comment: theres all my code now...

Comment: also, value is the first half of the split, value 1 is the second half.. "MouseColorR": 211,      "MouseColorR" = value and 211, = value1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are populating `ary` via `Dim ary As String() = line.Split(":")`. You are reading each line from `C:\Users\Matthew\Documents\My Games\Terraria\config.json`

One of the lines of that file doesn't contain a `:`. So the `Split` creates an array of just one element. When you then call:

```
Dim value1 As String = ary(1).Trim()
```

you get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` as element 1 doesn't exist.

The solution is to test the array length and have you code handle a line without a `:` in a graceful fashion.

Comment: so if i wanted to fix this without deleting those brackets.. how would i do so? EDIT: Nvm i know how.. just declare it in the Try function

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing a container at position 0 which works and then at 1 which does not. The exception displayed in the screenshot says it's an out-of-range problem. So your container isn't as large as you expect: It has only 1 element.

Comment: If value = R Then
                MsgBox(ary(1).Trim(Chr(44)))                                                            end if

Comment: What about all the cases when value does not equal R?

Comment: R, G, B are all i care about.. anything else doesnt matter.. also the code is the same for all 3 of them besides the variable

Comment: The latter code works because you only test ary(1) when value = R. The former code fails because you access ary(1) even when value does not equal R.